# writing remove() methods for linked list class of any type

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having some problems writing a `remove()` method for a linked list class from scratch.

There are two `remove()` methods, one for simply removing the front of the linked list and another for removing the data at a specific index of the linked list.

I'm unsure of which one is broken, I think I have both correct but through running my class with another test file, `LinkedListTest`, I get this error message regarding the `remove()` methods:

```
Running Test remove tests (6 tests)
Starting tests: ....EE
Time: 0.004

There were 2 failures:
1) t44RemoveFromThreeItemList1(LinkedListTest$RemoveTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong item removed from One ItemList expected:<y> but was:<x>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        ... 11 more
2) t45RemoveFromThreeItemList2(LinkedListTest$RemoveTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong item removed from One ItemList expected:<z> but was:<y>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        ... 11 more

Test Failed! (2 of 6 tests failed.)

Test failures: abandoning other phases.
```

Any advice is appreciated, I've been looking at this for a long time and need some fresh eyes. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedList<E> {
   private class ListNode {
      E data;
      ListNode next;

      ListNode(E data) {
         this.data = data;
         next = null;
      }

      ListNode(E data, ListNode next) {
         this.data = data;
         this.next = next;
      }
   }


   private ListNode front;

   private int size;

   public LinkedList() {
      front = null;


   }  
   public int size() {
      return size;
   }
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      if (this.size == 0) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   public void add(E value) {
      this.size++;
      if (front == null) {
         front = new ListNode(value);
      } else {
         ListNode current = front;
         while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
         }
         current.next = new ListNode(value);
      }
   }

   public void add(int index, E value) {
       if (index == 0){
             front = new ListNode(value, front);
         }  
       else {
              ListNode curr = front;
              for   (int i =    0;  i < index - 1;  i++){
                    curr = curr.next;
              }
              curr.next = new   ListNode(value, curr.next);
         }
    }


   public E get(int index) {
      ListNode current = front;

      for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++, current = current.next) {
         if (i == index) {
            return current.data;
         }

      }
      return current.data;

   }
   public E remove() {
      ListNode result = front;
      front = front.next;
      size--;
      return result.data;


   }


   public E remove(int index) {
      ListNode result;
      if (index < 0 || index >= this.size()) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

      }
      if    (index == 0){
          result = front;
             front =    front.next;
          size--;
          return result.data;

        } else {
             ListNode curr = front;
             for (int i = 1; i <    index; i++){
                curr = curr.next;
             }

          result = curr;
             curr.next = curr.next.next;

        }
      size--;
      return result.data;


    }
```

Also, here is the relevant section of the test file, for context:

```
  public static class RemoveTest {   

      // Maximum 10 milliseconds for all tests
      @Rule public Timeout timeout = new Timeout(10);

      LinkedList<Character> oneList = null;
      LinkedList<Character> threeList = null;

      @Before public void setUp() {
         oneList = new LinkedList<Character>();
         oneList.add('a');
         threeList = new LinkedList<Character>();
         threeList.add('x');
         threeList.add('y');
         threeList.add('z');
      }

      @Test public void t41RemoveFromOneItemList() {
         assertEquals("Wrong item removed from One ItemList",
            new Character('a'), oneList.remove());
         assertEquals("zero element list is not empty.",
            true, oneList.isEmpty());
         assertEquals("zero element list has wrong size.",
            0, oneList.size());
      }

      @Test public void t42RemoveFromOneItemList() {
         assertEquals("Wrong item removed from One ItemList",
            new Character('a'), oneList.remove(0));
         assertEquals("zero element list is not empty.",
            true, oneList.isEmpty());
         assertEquals("zero element list has wrong size.",
            0, oneList.size());
      }

      @Test public void t42RemoveFromThreeItemList() {
         assertEquals("Wrong item removed from One ItemList",
            new Character('x'), threeList.remove());
         assertEquals("two element list is empty.",
            false, threeList.isEmpty());
         assertEquals("two element list has wrong size.",
            2, threeList.size());
         assertEquals("get(0) on two element list is wrong.",
            new Character('y'), threeList.get(0));
      }

      @Test public void t43RemoveFromThreeItemList0() {
         assertEquals("Wrong item removed from One ItemList",
            new Character('x'), threeList.remove(0));
         assertEquals("two element list is empty.",
            false, threeList.isEmpty());
         assertEquals("two element list has wrong size.",
            2, threeList.size());
         assertEquals("get(0) on two element list is wrong.",
            new Character('y'), threeList.get(0));
      }

      @Test public void t44RemoveFromThreeItemList1() {
         assertEquals("Wrong item removed from One ItemList",
            new Character('y'), threeList.remove(1));
         assertEquals("two element list is empty.",
            false, threeList.isEmpty());
         assertEquals("two element list has wrong size.",
            2, threeList.size());
         assertEquals("get(0) on two element list is wrong.",
            new Character('x'), threeList.get(0));
         assertEquals("get(1) on two element list is wrong.",
            new Character('z'), threeList.get(1));
      }

      @Test public void t45RemoveFromThreeItemList2() {
         assertEquals("Wrong item removed from One ItemList",
            new Character('z'), threeList.remove(2));
         assertEquals("two element list is empty.",
            false, threeList.isEmpty());
         assertEquals("two element list has wrong size.",
            2, threeList.size());
         assertEquals("get(1) on two element list is wrong.",
            new Character('y'), threeList.get(1));
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on your `remove(index)` method. In the loop, if you want to start the iteration with `index = 1` you have to initialize `curr` with `front.next`, otherwise you miss a step. IMHO, this is better to do:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    ListNode result;
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    }
    ListNode curr = front;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
       curr = curr.next;
    }

    // front case added
    if(index == 0){
        front = curr.next;
    }

    result = curr;
    curr.next = curr.next.next;

    size--;
    return result.data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I replace the code, but still received the same error :/

Comment: @beachtowel I forget the "front case (index == 0)", so I update me answer. But I think there is an error on your tests, because each test modify the `threeList`. After the first `remove(0)` which remove the `x` element, the indexes change. `y` is now at index 0, so this is normal that the test t44 fails.